# How to define multiple belongsTo in laravel

Tags: laravel, orm, laravel-7, laravel-relations

My table has many foreign key for example prefecture_id, gender_id and status_id.

And I made model for those table.

So I want to define multiple belongsTo method like following for get all data with query builder..

But In fact belongsTo can't use like this.

```
public function foreign(){

 return $this->belongsTo([
   'App/Prefecture',
   'App/Gender',                        
   'App/Status',
]
}
```

And if the only way is defining multiple method for belongs to.

How do I get all belongstos data in querybuilder.

Please give me advice.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there's not a way to get multiple `belongsTo` from a single method. What you have to do is make one method for each relationship and when you want to load the relationships you can do the following.

#### Model

```php
public function prefecture()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Prefecture::class);
}

public function gender()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Gender::class);
}

public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Status::class);
}
```

#### Query

```php
// This will get your model with all of the belongs to relationships.

$results = Model::query()->with(['prefecture', 'gender', 'status'])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !  I know this way.  Response data has object.  But I wanted to get directly assigned data to table column name. There is no way ?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you’re trying to achieve? You can edit your original question with what you envision the end goal to be.